# How can access to all Tables using LinqDataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, aspxgridview

I have a problem withlinq entity-frameworks. So I have a `.dbml` file named

```
CustomerLicensesInstallation.dbml
```

In this file I have 4 tables of mssql db.

My tables and their relasoship is in bellow 

Tables
1. `PrescribingUnit` 
2. `Customers`
3. `Licenses` and 
4. `Installations`

relasoships
`Customers` connected with  `PrescribingUnit` like `One To Many` `1-N`
`Customers` connected with  `Licenses` like `One To Many` `1-N`
`Licenses` connected with  `Installations` like `One To One` `1-1`

How I am trying to show these data in a gridview using asp.net and C#. 
I want to show all data of table `PrescribingUnit` with their `customers` and `Licenses`
I'm using LinqDataSource and when trying to show with `Eval` it shows nothing.

I'm using below code for a column for `GridView`.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Serial Number" >
      <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:Label ID="LabelLicenseSerialNumber" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("licenses.license_serial_number") %>'>
        </asp:Label>
      </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Customer Name" >
          <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:Label ID="LabelCustomerFullName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("customers.full_name") %>'>
            </asp:Label>
          </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Prescribing Unit" >
              <ItemTemplate>
               <asp:Label ID="LabelPrescribingUnit" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("prescribingunit.unit") %>'>
                </asp:Label>
              </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>
```

The GridView DataSource is

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewSerials" runat="server" CellPadding="4" 
            ForeColor="#333333" Width="100%" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" 
            CellSpacing="2" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" 
            ShowFooter="True"
            EmptyDataText="No Log Messages" DataSourceID="LinqDataSource1" 
            AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            DataKeyNames="license_id" 
            PageSize="50" 
            DataMember="DefaultView">
```

And asp:LinqDataSource is

```
<asp:LinqDataSource ID="LinqDataSource1" runat="server" TableName="licenses" 
                ContextTypeName="ActivationWebService.LinqToSqlClasses.CustomerLicensesInstallationDataContext" 
                EntityTypeName="">
            </asp:LinqDataSource>
```

And `CustomerLicensesInstallationDataContext` is an autogenerated code

```
#pragma warning disable 1591
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.18051
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace ActivationWebService.LinqToSqlClasses
{


    public partial class license : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private static PropertyChangingEventArgs emptyChangingEventArgs = new PropertyChangingEventArgs(String.Empty);

    private long _id;

    private System.DateTime _issue_date;

    private System.DateTime _expiration_date;

    private System.DateTime _installation_date;

    private string _serial_number;

    private int _number_of_installations;

    private bool _is_active;

    private long _id_customers;

    private long _id_editions;

    private EntityRef<installations> _installations;

    private EntityRef<customers> _customer;

#region Extensibility Method Definitions

#endregion

    public license()
    {
        this._installations = default(EntityRef<installations>);
        this._customer = default(EntityRef<customers>);
        OnCreated();
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Name="id", Storage="_id", AutoSync=AutoSync.OnInsert, DbType="BigInt NOT NULL IDENTITY", IsPrimaryKey=true, IsDbGenerated=true)]
    public long license_id
    {
        get
        {
            return this._id;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._id != value))
            {
                this.Onlicense_idChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._id = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("license_id");
                this.Onlicense_idChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Name="issue_date", Storage="_issue_date", DbType="Date NOT NULL")]
    public System.DateTime license_issue_date
    {
        get
        {
            return this._issue_date;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._issue_date != value))
            {
                this.Onlicense_issue_dateChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._issue_date = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("license_issue_date");
                this.Onlicense_issue_dateChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Name="expiration_date", Storage="_expiration_date", DbType="Date NOT NULL")]
    public System.DateTime license_expiration_date
    {
        get
        {
            return this._expiration_date;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._expiration_date != value))
            {
                this.Onlicense_expiration_dateChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._expiration_date = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("license_expiration_date");
                this.Onlicense_expiration_dateChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Name="installation_date", Storage="_installation_date", DbType="Date NOT NULL")]
    public System.DateTime license_installation_date
    {
        get
        {
            return this._installation_date;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._installation_date != value))
            {
                this.Onlicense_installation_dateChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._installation_date = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("license_installation_date");
                this.Onlicense_installation_dateChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Name="serial_number", Storage="_serial_number", DbType="NVarChar(256) NOT NULL", CanBeNull=false)]
    public string license_serial_number
    {
        get
        {
            return this._serial_number;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._serial_number != value))
            {
                this.Onlicense_serial_numberChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._serial_number = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("license_serial_number");
                this.Onlicense_serial_numberChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Name="number_of_installations", Storage="_number_of_installations", DbType="Int NOT NULL")]
    public int license_number_of_installations
    {
        get
        {
            return this._number_of_installations;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._number_of_installations != value))
            {
                this.Onlicense_number_of_installationsChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._number_of_installations = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("license_number_of_installations");
                this.Onlicense_number_of_installationsChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Name="is_active", Storage="_is_active", DbType="Bit NOT NULL")]
    public bool license_is_active
    {
        get
        {
            return this._is_active;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._is_active != value))
            {
                this.Onlicense_is_activeChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._is_active = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("license_is_active");
                this.Onlicense_is_activeChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Name="id_customers", Storage="_id_customers", DbType="BigInt NOT NULL")]
    public long license_id_customers
    {
        get
        {
            return this._id_customers;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._id_customers != value))
            {
                this.Onlicense_id_customersChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._id_customers = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("license_id_customers");
                this.Onlicense_id_customersChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Name="id_editions", Storage="_id_editions", DbType="BigInt NOT NULL")]
    public long license_id_editions
    {
        get
        {
            return this._id_editions;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._id_editions != value))
            {
                this.Onlicense_id_editionsChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._id_editions = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("license_id_editions");
                this.Onlicense_id_editionsChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.AssociationAttribute(Name="license_installations", Storage="_installations", ThisKey="license_id", OtherKey="installation_id_licenses", IsUnique=true, IsForeignKey=false)]
    public installations installations
    {
        get
        {
            return this._installations.Entity;
        }
        set
        {
            installations previousValue = this._installations.Entity;
            if (((previousValue != value) 
                        || (this._installations.HasLoadedOrAssignedValue == false)))
            {
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                if ((previousValue != null))
                {
                    this._installations.Entity = null;
                    previousValue.license = null;
                }
                this._installations.Entity = value;
                if ((value != null))
                {
                    value.license = this;
                }
                this.SendPropertyChanged("installations");
            }
        }
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.AssociationAttribute(Name="customers_license", Storage="_customer", ThisKey="license_id_customers", OtherKey="id", IsForeignKey=true)]
    public customers customers
    {
        get
        {
            return this._customer.Entity;
        }
        set
        {
            customers previousValue = this._customer.Entity;
            if (((previousValue != value) 
                        || (this._customer.HasLoadedOrAssignedValue == false)))
            {
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                if ((previousValue != null))
                {
                    this._customer.Entity = null;
                    previousValue.licenses.Remove(this);
                }
                this._customer.Entity = value;
                if ((value != null))
                {
                    value.licenses.Add(this);
                    this._id_customers = value.id;
                }
                else
                {
                    this._id_customers = default(long);
                }
                this.SendPropertyChanged("customers");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangingEventHandler PropertyChanging;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void SendPropertyChanging()
    {
        if ((this.PropertyChanging != null))
        {
            this.PropertyChanging(this, emptyChangingEventArgs);
        }
    }

    protected virtual void SendPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        if ((this.PropertyChanged != null))
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
}
#pragma warning restore 1591
```

My problem is `Eval("prescribingunit.unit")`. 
I can show data from this table. If I change the main table from `license` to `customer` then it works for tables `customers` and `prescribingunit` but doesnt for `licenses`.
To fixe it I create a view in my database (msssql) and it works fine for now. 
But I would ask to you if has an other solution for these situations.

Comment: Can you show the code where you set the `GridView.DataSource` ?

Comment: @Rameez Ahmed Sayad - I edit my question please check again. The autogerated code is very big and I added only hafe code

Comment: didn't require the complete autogenerated the code , the class names and property were enough , wouldn't the `Eval` be  `license.license_serial_number` or simply `license_serial_number` ?

Comment: Yes you're write. It is Eval license_serial_number. I edit my question. My problem is Eval("prescribingunit.unit"). I can show data from this table. If I change the main table from license to customer then it works for tables customers and prescribingunit but doesnt for licenses.

Comment: Honestly I would any day prefer Entity Framework to Linq2Sql , it is much easier and better in all aspects else I would downgrade to ADO.NET but Linq2Sql gives lot of issues esp related to table relationships.

Comment: whitch technique do you prefer to connect ms sql and GridViews?

Comment: the disconnected architecture would be `Entity Framework` , regarding the `GridView` part , I generally don't use asp controls much since `Jquery`, `AJAX` and `JQuery plugins` are much lighter and faster. You can also use embedded c# in aspx to bind the class object to html table rows and columns.